# Laravel Nova Order By on Relatable Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova, laravel-5.8

I need to apply an order on a relatable query in Laravel Nova.

I've tried everything on this page https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/156 and can't get any of the methods detailed to work with my application.

I have 3 models significant to this problem; Event, Brand and Vehicle.

Events Belong To Many Brands | Brands Belong To Many Events

Brand Has Many Vehicles | Vehicles Belong To a Brand

Event Belongs To Many Vehicles | Vehicles Belong To Many Events

When a user creates an Event, they then go on to choose Brands associated with that Event.

This is facilitated by putting the below line in the fields function in my Nova Event Resource.

`BelongsToMany::make('Brand')->sortable(),`

Once a user has attached associated Brands, they then go on to attach associated Vehicles.

The list of Vehicles is populated using a relatable query that I have in my Nova Event Resource;

```
public static function relatableVehicles(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{

    $event = $request->findResourceOrFail();

    $brand_ids = [];

    foreach($event->brand as $brand) {
        $brand_ids[] = $brand['id'];
    }

    return $query->whereIn('brand_id', $brand_ids);

}
```

Now when I go to attach a Vehicle, it is populated only by Vehicles that are related to the Brands attached to the Event.

The problem is that the options in the select box provided are ordered by the title.

I have the below in my Vehicle resource, which I think is where the problem stems from;

`public static $title = 'model';`

But obviously I need that in the Resource so that the select box displays appropriately.

Does anyone know how I can order by something other than title instead? I'm trying to order by brand_id.